# In Dax, trying to use Treatas() gives me unexpected results for a similarly coded dax formula

Tags: dax

I have a Dax measure which works correctly.

```
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[reportId], 
        'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[lcv], 
        'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[grade]),
    var lcv = 'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[lcv]
    var grade = 'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[grade] 
    var reportid = 'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[reportId]  
    return  CALCULATE(
                [Sub Consumption], 
                'public bunker_zn_noonreport_sub_consumption'[reportId] = reportid,
                'public bunker_zn_noonreport_sub_consumption'[grade] = grade ) 
                * lcv/41600
)
```

I understand that a similar output can be obtained by using Treatas(), which might potentially be more optimised.
So I wrote the following formula:

```
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[reportId], 
        'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[lcv], 
        'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[grade]
        ),
    var lcv = 'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[lcv]
      
    var subconsumption =   CALCULATE(
                            [Sub Consumption], 
                            TREATAS(
                                SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                                    'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[reportId], 
                                    'public bunker_zn_noonreport_main_consumption'[grade]
                                    ),
                                'public bunker_zn_noonreport_sub_consumption'[reportId],
                                'public bunker_zn_noonreport_sub_consumption'[grade]) 
                            )
    var normalisedssubconsumption = subconsumption*lcv/41600
    return normalisedssubconsumption
)
```

Using the relationship with date, in my report, at the reported date level, both formulae work correctly.
However, at the total level, the second one computes it as a multiple of the number of reports that are visible in the report. In the image attached, it's twice, as there are two reports.

[row level, all good. total level it gets messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4V66.png)

Can you help me figure out where I'm going wrong.

I expected the outputs of the two measures to be the same. and they nearly are. except at the totals level.